# R - Filling in empty variables

Tags: r, dataframe

Given:

```
v1 <- c(1,NA,1,NA,NA)  
v2 <- c(NA,NA,1,NA,1)   
df <- data.frame(rbind(v1, v2))

R> df
X1 X2 X3 X4 X5    
1  NA  1 NA NA   
NA NA  1 NA  1
```

How can I fill in the `'NA'` between the `1`?

so that it looks like this:

```
X1 X2 X3 X4 X5   
1  1  1  NA NA 
NA NA 1  1  1
```

Comment: There are multiple ways of doing this. What have you tried?

Comment: Will each row only ever have 2 columns with a value of 1? Is there the possibility for more 1s? Fewer 1s? What behavior do you want in those cases?

Comment: Just consider the simplest case, in which, each row has 2 values of 1s. They can be adjacent (which can be left untouched) and ones where the value is missing in between. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how big your datasets are, but you can probably take a longer approach and get some more efficient results using approaches like either of the following:

Option 1: Using `arr.ind`.

```
library(data.table)
myFun1 <- function(indf) {
  M <- as.matrix(data.table(which(indf == 1, arr.ind = TRUE))[
    , list(col = seq.int(min(col), max(col))), row])
  indf[M] <- 1
  indf
}
myFun1(df)
```

Option 2: Using `max.col`.

```
myFun2 <- function(indf) {
  indf2 <- replace(indf, is.na(indf), 0)
  mins <- max.col(indf2, "first")
  maxs <- max.col(indf2, "last")
  L <- Map(seq.int, mins, maxs)
  mat <- cbind(rep(seq_along(L), lengths(L)), unlist(L, use.names = FALSE))
  indf[mat] <- 1
  indf
}
myFun2(df)
```

Test it out with some data of different sizes. Here's one approach to make the data:

```
set.seed(1)
nc <- 50
nr <- 10000
df <- data.frame(t(replicate(nr, sample(c(1, 1, rep(NA, nc-2))))))
```

---

See [**this Gist**](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/048f4323217bade1168a9b3dff521b22) for some sample output and timing comparisons.

Answer (score 2):

We can do this by looping through the rows with `apply` with `MARGIN=1`.  Find the index of first and last non-NA elements and change the elements in between with the first non-NA element, transpose the output and assign it back to the dataset.

```
df[] <- t(apply(df, 1, function(x) {
         st <- range(which(!is.na(x)))
          x[st[1]:st[2]] <- x[st[1]]
          x}))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another `apply` solution on `MARGIN=2` with the usage of the `lag` and `lead` functions from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)


v1 <- c(1,NA,1,NA,NA)  
v2 <- c(NA,NA,1,NA,1)   
dff <- data.frame(rbind(v1, v2))

apply(t(dff), 2, function(x) {
    conds <- rowSums(cbind(x, lag(x), lead(x)), na.rm = T)==2
    x[conds] <- 1
    x
}) %>% t()
```

Outputs:

```
#    X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
# v1  1  1  1 NA NA
# v2 NA NA  1  1  1
```

Comment: In case anyone is curious about my previous comment, check out https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/048f4323217bade1168a9b3dff521b22.